# Can Urysohn's lemma be applied to find a function that is 0 inside a neighbourhood $U$ and equal to a given function outside $\bar{U}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $g\in C(X)$ be such that $g(x_{0})=0$, for some $x_{0}\in X$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, can we find a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_{0}$ and $f\in C(X)$ such that $f\restriction_U=0$ and $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$? Here is what I have tried so far. Given $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists U$, a neighbourhood of $x_{0}$ such that $|g(x)|<\varepsilon, x\in U$. We can find $f\in C(X)$ such that $f\restriction U=0$ and equal to some constant outside $\bar{V}$ by Urysohn's Lemma. Can we instead ask that $f=g$ outside $\bar{U}$? This would ensure that $\|f-g\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need anything so fancy.  Let $f(x) = h(g(x))$ where 
$$ h(t) = \cases {t - \varepsilon/2 & if $t > \varepsilon/2$\cr
                 0 & if $-\varepsilon/2 \le t \le \varepsilon/2$\cr
                 t + \varepsilon/2 & if $t < -\varepsilon/2$\cr} $$